# What is this script doing?

Tags: javascript, performance, web

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 application.
This referrs a Js file like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:32967/Scripts/MyScripts/Myscript.js"></script>
```

There was a blocking time seen in the browser while downloading this script.
Googling for this, I found a reference [here](http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/avoid-javascript-blocking-content-download-on-your-website-during-page-load/)

When this script is added the blocking is gone.
In fact there is no blocking seen for any more script references added.
This had a major speed boost.

Can someone please explain what this script does?
If blocking can be avoided by doing this then why is this not a best practice?

[**Update**]
I have changed the script name from Reference.js to MyScript.js as it's causing confusion with the other question with the _reference.js.

Here are the contents of this file:

```
var urls = {
commonUrl: "http://localhost:32944/",
myappurl: "http://localhost:32967/",
productUrl: "http://localhost:49880/"
}
```

That's all there is in that file.

Regards.

Comment: what does `References.js` in its context, as far as I know, we have something like `_references.js` in ASP.Net MVC, add the content of this file to the post. check if it has references like `/// <reference path="jquery-1.6.2.js" />` in it.

Comment: Reference.js is a Js used by this app. Doesn't have any reference to any other js files.

Comment: @Kuzgun How is this a duplicate of that?

Comment: Your question is unclear in many ways. 1: You contradict yourself when stating a) "There was a blocking time seen in the browser(..)" and b) "When this script is added the blocking is gone". 2: Are you asking what the SCRIPT does or what the script TAG does? If you're asking about the SCRIPT please provide the contents. 3: as for "best practice", what practice are you talking about? The practice of adding script tags to an HTML file?

Comment: Ok I get it now, "This script" is not referring to Myscript.js, but to the script at http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/avoid-javascript-blocking-content-download-on-your-website-during-page-load/

Answer (score 1):

References.js is only [used by the Visual Studio IDE](http://gurustop.net/blog/2012/03/03/javascript-js-intellisense-auto_complete-in-visual-studio-11-beta-the-web-_references-js-file/) as a list of files to which provide Intellisense for. It is *not* included in any HTML file as a script reference by the basic template, as I interpret you claim in your question.

If anything, adding the script reference should slow down load time. I'm going out on a limb here and claiming your measurements are wrong - that adding this script in no way can speed up loading time of any web page.

**edit**: I see you have updated your question now. If this indeed is not _references.js, then you need to provide the content of the file for us to give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You ask two questions:

**What does it do?** It fools the browser in thinking there are no script references in this HTML page, only a single inline script. By doing this it circumvents the standard load procedure which results in the scripts being loaded at a later point than normal, and asynchronously. Why exactly this results in asynchronous loading you must ask the implementors of the different browsers. It may not be true for all.

**Why is it not best practice?** I can think of multiple reasons:

1. It comes with side effects
2. It is a more verbose, less readable format
3. It breaks the HTML standard
4. It breaks SEO and other machine parsing of the HTML

As for #1: By loading and *running* asynchronously you no longer have control over which script executes first. There may be dependencies between the scripts, which will result in runtime errors when done in wrong order. If you could solve the problem of running in order while still loading asynchronously (totally doable), you'll be fine though.

Then again, you should rather push the browser implementors to fix this instead of implementing this rather ugly hack. There are many other more viable ways of improving page load time better than this. Caching, minifying and bundling are three that jumps to mind.

Lastly I'm assuming you have added a *working* implementation of the script referenced at the [webdigi](http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/avoid-javascript-blocking-content-download-on-your-website-during-page-load/) blog. The blog itself is good at explaining the concept, but awful on code examples as it does not provide insight in what the poorly named variables n,k,e, g and C should represent. Here is a working implementation for reference and context of what I'm talking about, which loads JQuery and JQuery UI. Note that since JQuery UI depends on JQuery core being loaded first, this example will only work half the time:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var headNode = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0];
            // Jquery
            var c1 = document.createElement("script");
            c1.type= "text/javascript";
            c1.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js";

            // JQuery UI
            var c2 = document.createElement("script");
            c2.type= "text/javascript";
            c2.src = "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js";

            headNode.appendChild(c1);
            headNode.appendChild(c2);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Content goes here
    </body>
</html>
```